# how I replace IP address of my email addresses with domain name?

Tags: domain, cpanel

I have domain name registered on `easyDns.com` and `VPS` hosting on `godaddy`.

I changed the A record for my domain in easyDNS and it worked. It redirects to my IP address.

But when I create email address from cpanel. The email address becomes like `info@192.168.8.8`
But I want `info@xample.com`

please guide me.

Comment: Its not entirely clear where you want to change it. Is it the Technical or Administrative contact in the WHOIS database? You might want to checkout [EasyDNS Support](https://support.easydns.com/) page.

Comment: Have you changed the Local /etc/hosts file on the VPS to indicate  that   __192.168.8.8__ IS localhost and that localhost IS __example.com__ (whatever is set at easyDNS) ?

Comment: using SSH
in th etc/hosts I found:


127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
127.0.0.1               localhost ip-104-238-95-53
104.238.95.53           ip-104-238-95-53.secureserver.net ip-104-238-95-53

Comment: @linuxdev2013 pleaes help me out

Comment: `192.168.8.8` is not valid outside of your network. 127.0.0.1 also wouldn't be valid outside of your network.  Its unlikely your email works currently if your using either.

Comment: @Sarah, use  curl ident.me  from a linux /mac cli terminal or powershell on windows (or  head to http://whatsmyipaddress.com )   and use THAT address in place of 192.x.y.z

Comment: SO ON the VPS the /etc/hosts file would have a  line like __ 98.191.1.0    localhost   and your have the mail server use localhost

Comment: @linuxdev2013 write a complete solution pls

Answer (score 0):

IN `/etc/hosts`  on your VPS  you should see something like:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6


## Entries below this line are added by the user and ** ARE NOT ** Defaults
127.0.0.1    (localhostname.domainname)

98.132.125.0   example.com  ## replace this lines info with the IP addr your get from http://whatsmyipaddress.com (FROM VPS ) and the domainame instead of example.com
```

Comment: Please use the preview function below your post before submitting and indent code by 4 spaces.